# Beginning a sentence with a gerund?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, gerunds, sentence-starts, is-it-a-rule

My teacher recently marked on my paper not to use a gerund to start a sentence. I have been told by teachers in the past to use that format to vary sentence structure. It seems to make the paper flow better oftentimes. An example:

> Learning to confront his problems is an important part of [character's] growth and maturity in the novel.

Is there a grammar rule about this? I haven't ever heard/seen one before.

**Edit**: It would also be helpful to know of any good examples or arguments I would be able to use when discussing this.

Comment: If you wrote that sentence, then I assure you - as a trainer for people learning t write English for university purposes - that your sentence is excellent in terms of the English!

Comment: related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-does-one-know-when-to-use-a-gerund-or-an-infinitive and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/gerund-phrase-as-subject

Comment: related and possible duplicate [difference between a gerund acting as subject and an infinitive acting as a subject](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177437/difference-between-a-gerund-acting-as-subject-and-an-infinitive-acting-as-a-subj)

Comment: Is there a way to revoke your teacher's certification ?

Comment: Telling people a stylistic preference is a grammar rule is the sign of a rigid mind. Gerund away, baby, gerund away!

Comment: I suggest you confront the problem with your teacher's 'correction' by asking them to explain the grammatical justification for it. It may help you to think of it as giving your teacher an opportunity to learn something.

Comment: The answers and comments provide a large set of illustrative refutations to your teacher's "rule".  Just show him/her this question on ELU.  Perhaps your teacher will enjoy participating here!  We'd love to set this teacher straight!

Comment: @Cyberherbalist In the 1.5 months I've been in class, I'm assuming that she would not appreciate it. Nor would she be happy if she knew that I asked about it on the site at all. Better not to get on the wrong side of her in the first quarter.

Comment: I am sure you are correct! You are, of course, the best judge of your situation.

Comment: Examples
"Sleeping much is not conducive for health"
"Exercising regularly and sensibly is a key to good health"

Answer (score 14):

Believing your teacher would be a mistake.  (Did you see what I just did?)

Comment: Hmm, would upvote,but that's just a comment as it stands!

Comment: Answering with a comment is fine in this case. (Did you see what I just did?) Besides, how else would you prove the non-existence of a rule, other than with a counterexample?

Comment: This answer is really a comment. Araucaria is correct. To be a genuine answer (as opposed to a comment) it would explain *why* it is okay to start a sentence with a gerund.

Comment: @200_success but how do we know the counterexample isn't just as wrong? It breaks the exact same rule. Repetition of assertion is no proof.

Comment: (...and as a personal aside, "did you see what I just did" is right up there with ["pun intended"](http://www.thebestpageintheuniverse.net/c.cgi?u=puns).)

Answer (score 1):

Gerund as subject: Smoking is bad for your health.

See link
http://www.grammaring.com/the-gerund-as-subject

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree that there is nothing grammatically wrong with starting a sentence with a gerund phrase; however, I do tell my AP students to avoid the construction because it almost always leads to the use of a linking verb, as is the case with the example. If we all agree that the use of action verbs is preferable, then the use of the gerund phrase as the subject of a sentence should be avoided. I often have students write (in a literary analysis), "By using the ..." I simply tell them to cross out the 'by' and use the participial phrase instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be a little careful about our poor teacher. I feel that the proposed examples don't illustrate the **true** *gerund*. In each case the gerund phrase was functionally used as a (compound) **noun**. The typical usages in a sentence would have one activity while another is happening at the same time.

*(DISCLAIMER--I am not any expert nor a native English speaker).*

Comment: Like _Swimming across the river, the crocodile approached_ ?

Comment: In which _Swimming_ is not a gerund.

Comment: Isn't a gerund, by definition, a noun?  The Swimming here is an adjective, hence a participle.  It is a swimming crocodile.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that you were committing logic errors with dangling modifiers. It is not all out "WRONG" to use a gerund at the start of the sentence. Many writers young and not so young, however, can mix up the meaning they are trying to convey if the sentence has more than one subject possibly tied to the gerund.

For example:
Running to the bus, Jillian saw her friend Tom 
*(or for that matter)*
 Jillian saw her friend Tom running to the bus.

The dangling modifiers above generate confusion. (Who was running to the bus?)
 Both of the problematic forms could mean either:

(1) As she ran to the bus Jillian saw her friend Tom.

*(as compared to)* 
(2) Jillian saw her friend Tom as he ran to the bus.

Comment: Those aren't gerunds, they are participles.

Answer (score -2):

1. The teacher was right. In the example, the initial gerund creates a poor sentence structure that needs to be improved by rephrasing. Do not use an initial gerund **in such sentences.** This is about writing style and readability.
2. The teacher was wrong in not explaining that this is not about grammar, certainly not a rule.

**See our sister site [writers.se]  **

Comment: Could you please clarify what "such sentences" are and why you think they are bad style?

Comment: That's better dealt with on writers.se

Comment: Although I think you're onto something because the OP teacher didn't say *never* start a sentence with a gerund. How would you improve the style of this sentence? Why does the gerund impede readability in this case?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see anything wrong with the sentence, including poor structure.  Perhaps you should demonstrate an improvement by rephrasing?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The note on the paper says "Do not begin a sentence with a gerund." That seems pretty definite to me.

Comment: @erdekhayser I'm giving the teacher the benefit of the doubt. It could be that he/she didn't want you to start a sentence with *learning* on this occasion. I don't know.