# ending an email in relation to answering a job vacancy

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

I would like to end my email in relation to answering a job vacancy as
"I look forward with anticipation"
Kind regard
Jackie
(my CV will be attached)

Or should I say 
"looking forward to hearing from you"
Kind regards
Jackie
The latter I feel makes an assumption they like what's said in my CV

Comment: 'Look/ing forward' needs 'to ...'.

Comment: This sounds more like a philosophical question than a grammatical one. The first version needs some grammatical revision, but neither is more intrinsically better than the other.

Comment: Not entirely sure how you can be looking forward *without* anticipation. Meaning to say, you have quite some pointless piling on of valedictions and verbiages there. Makes you sound fake and phony, is what it does. And also wastes the reader's time. Nobody cares what you do or do not look forward to. Least of all the poor people in HR that have to read that phony nonsense all day long. Don't be yet another person in that crowd they don't care about. Stand out by being genuinely polite and wonderfully concise. Say "Kind regards" and leave it at that.

Comment: Many words have been used in answer to my question, for which I am grateful but uneducated as to their meaning so I think I'll stick to regDwight's advice.

Answer (score 0):

The first one seems too formal and the second one is not a complete sentence. You can use the second one better, like:

> Looking forward to your response,
>
> Jackie

Comment: I don't see how "**Looking forward to hearing from you**, (space) kind regards, Jackie" is not a complete sentence, but "*Looking forward to your response*" is?

Comment: @aesking My version isn't a complete sentence either, so I don't use it as a sentence in the body of my email nor put a period after it. Send-offs before signing your name, like "sincerely," are usually not sentences. I suggested that  if she wants to use option 2, to use it like I did. Hope that clarifies things; sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi, both sentences are complete sentences, it's just an informal way of saying "**I** look forward to your response" with the subject omitted. See [conversational deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask)

Comment: Also pulled this from that answer: It is not good formal written style, except for reporting dialog in a story.

Comment: That is true. Personally, I am susceptible to beginning sentences with a [gerund](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203840/beginning-a-sentence-with-a-gerund) in letters too! I'm not sure what the convention is but, it's best to consider formality on a scale from extremely formal to extremely informal. Letters are usually in the middle. For example, in formal writing, it is recommended to not use contractions and such, but even the best people do it (unconsciously) and it's often overlooked. And I think it's becoming more acceptable to use contractions in academic essays.

Comment: I agree with everything you said. I would still suggest, because this letter is going to a potential employer, to err on the formal side of things. Thank you for showing me the conversational deletion by the way!

Comment: Hi Pink...another fix for block quote...please check out how i did it by clicking on the edit icon on the bottom of your Q.